# trouble with ctrl plus click of href=#

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I am working with Ember JS. I have an `<a>` tag on click of which i submit a form from JS and navigate to the target url. Everything works fine.

For showing the pointer icon, i used `href="#"` on the HTML. As i have been doing for ages.

Now suddenly the QA decides to do right click and open in new tab or CTRL Click. Now what happens is, a new tab is opened with the URL like this.

`www.something.com/index.html/#` beacuse href was #.

And the QA expects to see the target page in the new tab

I have two fixes.

1. Remove href = # and give CSS pointer style. So that new tab does not work
2. Somehow open the tab and do the form post in the new tab.

Is 2 possible?

Comment: Using javascript to alter the semantic meaning of links and QA wanting to be able to invoke that functionality in ways other than single left-clicking on it are never going to mix well.

Comment: I would add the cursor class, not get inventive with new solutions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rather than 'hacking' an `a` tag to get the pointer, you can use `cursor:pointer` in your CSS.

DEMO:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: tomato;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.curs {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>no cursor</div>
<div class="curs">cursor</div>
```

---

Since you are using this for a 'submitting a form', I would suggest using an

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

as this would submit the form for you.

Comment: this is same as solution 1 i pointed out. Is solution 2 acheivable?

Comment: @aneeshere: I see option 2 as a *hack* whilst the second part of my answer should be what you're looking to do (use the submit there - that's what it's meant for). Opening a tab just to submit a form would be *extremely* bad practise, and I would advise not even going there. You're first 'solution' would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fake tag! Say, `span.link`:

```css
.link {color: #00f; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<span class="link">Is this a link?</span><br />
<a href="#">Is this a link?</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can take a different **approach**, just try

```
function removeHashAndGo(){
   var url_wo_hash = this.hash.substr(1);
   window.open(url_wo_hash, "_blank"); //opens in a new window without #
}

$('#your_anchor_id').click(removeHashAndGo); //on click will call fn removeHashAndGo()
```